# Which list<Object> implementation will be the fastest for one pass write, read, then destroy?

Tags: java, list, collections, big-o

What is the fastest list implementation (in java) in a scenario where the list will be created one element at a time then at a later point be read one element at a time? The reads will be done with an iterator and then the list will then be destroyed.
I know that the Big O notation for get is O(1) and add is O(1) for an ArrayList, while LinkedList is O(n) for get and O(1) for add. Does the iterator behave with the same Big O notation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends largely on whether you know the maximum size of each list up front.

If you do, use `ArrayList`; it will certainly be faster.

Otherwise, you'll probably have to profile. While access to the `ArrayList` is O(1), creating it is not as simple, because of dynamic resizing.

Another point to consider is that the space-time trade-off is not clear cut. Each Java object has quite a bit of overhead. While an `ArrayList` may waste some space on surplus slots, each slot is only 4 bytes (or 8 on a 64-bit JVM). Each element of a `LinkedList` is probably about 50 bytes (perhaps 100 in a 64-bit JVM). So you have to have quite a few wasted slots in an `ArrayList` before a `LinkedList` actually wins its presumed space advantage. Locality of reference is also a factor, and `ArrayList` is preferable there too.

In practice, I almost always use `ArrayList`.

Comment: References on 64-bit JVMs do not necessarily take up 8 bytes. They usually take 4 except for large heap sizes where CompressedOops is disabled.

Answer (score 10):

**First Thoughts:**

- Refactor your code to not need the list.
- Simplify the data down to a scalar data type, then use: **int[]**
- Or even just use an array of whatever object you have: **Object[]** - John Gardner
- Initialize the list to the full size: **new ArrayList(123);**

Of course, as everyone else is mentioning, do performance testing, prove your new solution is an improvement.

Comment: Or even just use an array of whatever object you have, if you can't simplify it to a scalar type.

Comment: This is a bad answer.  The performance cost here doesn't come from creating the list, it comes from choosing the wrong implementation based upon how he's using it.  Using an array over an ArrayList won't help if he's adding lots of objects because you still need a new array once you reach the max.

Comment: won't help if he's adding lots of objects because you still need a new array once you reach the max --- thats why i suggested initializing to the biggest size its gonna be.

Comment: More importantly, I'm simply listing some things they could try doing that MIGHT help, and if performance testing says they do help, then cool.

Comment: Re: Outlaw. We dont know where the performance cost is coming from, maybe its memory space, maybe there's a bandwidth issue, maybe its just raw CPU cycles (embedded Javelin Stamp stuff).

Answer (score 7):

Iterating through a linked list is O(1) per element.

The Big O runtime for each option is the same.  Probably the ArrayList will be faster because of better memory locality, but you'd have to measure it to know for sure.  Pick whatever makes the code clearest.

Answer (score 7):

Note that iterating through an instance of `LinkedList` can be O(n^2) if done naively.  Specifically:

```
List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.get(i);
}
```

This is absolutely horrible in terms of efficiency due to the fact that the list must be traversed up to `i` *twice* for each iteration.  If you do use `LinkedList`, be sure to use either an `Iterator` or Java 5's enhanced `for`-loop:

```
for (Object o : list) {
    // ...
}
```

The above code is O(n), since the list is traversed statefully in-place.

To avoid all of the above hassle, just use `ArrayList`.  It's not always the best choice (particularly for space efficiency), but it's usually a safe bet.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new List implementation called [GlueList](https://github.com/ertugrulcetin/GlueList) which is faster than all classic List implementations.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library

Comment: It is gentle and you should mention that you are the author of this implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly want an **ArrayList**. Both adding and reading are "amortized constant time" (i.e. O(1)) as specified in the documentation (note that this is true even if the list has to increase it's size - it's designed like that see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html ). If you know roughly the number of objects you will be storing then even the ArrayList size increase is eliminated.

Adding to the end of a linked list is O(1), but the constant multiplier is larger than ArrayList (since you are usually creating a node object every time). Reading is virtually identical to the ArrayList if you are using an iterator.

It's a good rule to always use the simplest structure you can, unless there is a good reason not to. Here there is no such reason.

The exact quote from the documentation for ArrayList is: "The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation."

Comment: Adding to `LinkedList` (which behaves as doubly-linked and maintains a reference to head and tail) is certainly *not* O(n) unless you are inserting at an arbitrary index. An insert into an `ArrayList` is *not* O(1) if it triggers an increase in capacity; it does use `System.arraycopy`, though.

Comment: Specifically the documentation says:

The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

Comment: The key word there is "amortized". That means they're distributing the cost of that one resize-triggering insert across all the other inserts for purposes of that calculation. Feel free to look at the source and see that it allocates a new, larger array and copies the elements from the old to new.

Comment: Thanks, I read the source a long time ago, and fully understand how ArrayList works, which is why I wrote that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest benchmarking it. It's one thing reading the API, but until you try it for yourself, it'd academic.

Should be fair easy to test, just make sure you do meaningful operations, or hotspot will out-smart you and optimise it all to a NO-OP :)

Answer (score -1):

I have actually begun to think that any use of data structures with non-deterministic behavior, such as ArrayList or HashMap, should be avoided, so I would say only use ArrayList if you can bound its size; any unbounded list use LinkedList. That is because I mainly code systems with near real time requirements though.

The main problem is that any memory allocation (which could happen randomly with any add operation) could also cause a garbage collection, and any garbage collection can cause you to miss a target. The larger the allocation, the more likely this is to occur, and this is also compounded if you are using CMS collector. CMS is non-compacting, so finding space for a new linked list node is generally going to be easier than finding space for a new 10,000 element array.

The more rigorous your approach to coding, the closer you can come to real time with a stock JVM. But choosing only data structures with deterministic behavior is one of the first steps you would have to take.

Comment: Oh, and Vector is exactly the same as ArrayList, only with synchronization. Hardly anyone knows about the synchronization in Vector, so if you are depending on that thread safe behavior, it would be better to explicitely state that with something like Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList) instead.